# Alguien sabe porque muestra este error cuando creo un usuario con " sudo addgroup NOMBRE "

Tags: sql-server, servidor

[image: sudo addgroup NombreGrupo]

Alguien sabe como solucionar este error que me esta presentando despues de que pongo la contraseña?????

Comment: Bienvenido Warren a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Te comento algunas cosas: 1) Tu pregunta es más de administración de sistemas que de programación, por lo que debería cerrarse 2)  El problema es que el nombre del grupo no cumple con los requisitos del sistema, prueba sin las mayúsculas, ej:  `sudo addgroup ìnformaticadigital`

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no parece consistente con la temática del sitio.